# Getting started with WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Our company(Enterprise) have planned to use WSO2(EI/ESB) products for our systems that connects with each other by P2P.
So we needed integration solution and chose WSO2.
I am asking that Is it good to use WSO2 for huge systems (Middlewares, Web services, Gateway etc).

- Is WSO2 OK if there are a tons of request to handle?
- Is there any WSO2 Training Course (On-Site and Online)

Comment: Anyone who is familliar with WSO2 and have some experience about it 
I have few questions to ask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use WSO2 EI to achieve your need. Currently all WSO2 products are proven to build large scale platforms. You can visit [1] and find out large scale users and their stories.

> 1. Is WSO2 OK if there are a tons of request to handle?

Yes, EI (ESB profile) capable of handling huge request load and it is proven for example in ebay "WSO2 ESB to Process More Than 1 Billion Transactions Per Day" and many more.

> 2. Is there any WSO2 Training Course (On-Site and Online)

Of cource, WSO2 provide online certification, onsite/online product training and self learning materials. Please find more information at [2]

[1] https://wso2.com/about/customers/

[2] https://wso2.com/training

Thanks,
Milinda